# Compute $1! + 2! + 3! + ... + 2017! \pmod{100}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have no idea about how to solve this. It is impossible to solve by brute force, but only $1!,\ 2!,\ 3!$, and $4!$ leave mods of not $0$ when modded by $10$. So is it $1+2+6+24=33$?

Comment: Are you modding by 10 or by 100?

Comment: Every number n greater then 10 is $n!\equiv 0(mod 100)$, why?

Comment: Ah, because 5! is 120, ending in 0, and multiplying it by 10 gives it another 0, which leaves it 0 mod 100.

Comment: @arberavdullahu I think you meant greater THAN, but it is actually greater THAN or EQUAL to 10.

Comment: @GerardL. why do you change your post?

Comment: @Xam I figured it out, just checking if this is correct.

Comment: @GerardL. Did you note that somebody spent some time answering your question *as it was then*?

Comment: @Did For me, his answer post did not load in and I had figured out the problem remembering another problem I solved. I did not plagiarize his answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easy enough to see that since $n!=1\times2\times3\times\dots\times n$, then,

$$n!=0\pmod{100}\quad n\ge10$$

Thus, you problem reduces down to

$$1!+2!+3!+\dots+9!\equiv1+2+6+24+20+20+40+20+80\equiv13\pmod{100}$$